# Issue with linked file in forge design automation apis

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api, forge, autodesk-designautomation

We are using forge design automation apis in our project. We have a requirement where we need to pass linked file with are main revit file as shown below. We are using revit 2020 as engine.

```
|-- LinkA.rvt
|   |-- LinkA1.rvt
|   |-- LinkA2.rvt
|
|-- LinkB.rvt
```

But when we are getting the linked file using below code in c# revit addin. Then its return an empty array.

```
List<Element> linkCollector = new FilteredElementCollector(_doc).OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_RvtLinks).WhereElementIsNotElementType().ToList();
```

Can any one please help me to figure out the solution for this problem?

Comment: Does this code work for you locally and fail only on design automation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to find [RevitLinkInstance](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2020/a3a27c39-75bf-67d1-ae78-4cadd49a9c8e.htm) or [RevitLinkType](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2020/2204a5ab-6476-df41-116d-23dbe3cb5407.htm). The code you have seems to be trying to collect `RevitLinkInstance` and if you get an empty list, it is likely due to fact that there are no instances placed for the linked files in the host document.

Do you get an empty array if you drop `WhereElementIsNotElementType()` in your filter?

```cs
List<Element> linkCollector = new FilteredElementCollector(_doc).OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_RvtLinks).ToList();
```

To explicitly collect `RevitLinkType` you can also do:

```cs
List<Element> linkCollector = new FilteredElementCollector(_doc).OfClass(typeof(RevitLinkType)).ToList();
```

To explicitly collect `RevitLinkInstance` you can also do:

```cs
List<Element> linkCollector = new FilteredElementCollector(_doc).OfClass(typeof(RevitLinkInstance)).ToList();
```

Comment: Yes, I am still getting empty list after removing **WhereElementIsNotElementType()** from the filter.

Comment: All code samples above are rather basic. And I confirm they work as expected in standard cases. If you have an input file where it does not work as expected, please share the file or reach out to `forge[dot]help[at]autodesk.com`.